# In Genetic Engineering, why are we limited to existing creatures when it comes to creating a new species?

Tags: genetics

So, I don't know much about Biology. Haven't studied it since high school. So please excuse me if my science isn't proper. I'll do my best.

Let's say for example you wanted to make a fire breathing Komodo dragon. Well, from what I understand, it's quite impossible to do because there are no creatures that breathe fire. So you wouldn't be able to gather the needed DNA information for breathing fire.

However, if you wanted to give a Komodo dragon wings, well this would be possible, because there are many winged creatures in this world, so the genetic information you need is available.

What I don't understand is, why couldn't you create or manifest this genetic information artificially in a lab? What stops us from doing that? Say for example, fire breathing?

I'm not particularly interested in the utility behind fire breathing dragons. I'm just using it as an example for my question. Any other features could be added in it's place.

Answer (score -1):

Obligatory not a biologist, I studied physics.

In a very basic way, and ignoring the limits of carbon chemistry, it's all a question of understanding.

If you imagine DNA, and genetics as a whole akin to a language, we're currently barely able to read it, let alone write.

We know the letters of the genetic alphabet, at this point (Adenine, Thymine, Guanine and Cytosine, along with Uracil for RNA), and we're starting understand how to make a few words (genes), but we're still quite a ways away from mastery of the genetic language.

Part of the problem is that some traits have simple mechanisms that go from gene to expression, like how skin colour is largely based on the amount of melatonin in your skin-cells, and how eye colour largely hinges on one or two genes. However, many things are not that simple, from things like autism to adult height, to cancer, most parts of an animal don't hinge on a single gene. This also means that, in your example, we're nowhere close to making a komodo dragon grow wings.

To summarize, we've only barely figured out the genetic alphabet, along with a couple words, but we're nowhere near being able to write whole sentences, nor make up words from scratch.

Comment: Be careful when talking about stuff that you obviously don't know. Especially pigmentation and its regulation **is** a complicated field, although in the end the amount and ratio of the melanin (not melatonin!) is what makes the difference. Getting there is another story.